# Generating activities Dynamically

Tags: android

I have an application in which according to the user input , i have to display activities..
Plz specify how can i display activities dynamically . 
Already keeping the maximum no of activities and displaying it them using intent is definitely  not a viable option..

How can i achieve this?z

```
public class Progress extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
Button b;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.progress);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

switch(view.getId()){

 case R.id.b:

 String numberPos = et.getText.toString();
 int n = Integer.parseInt(numberPos);


  break;

}

}
```

Comment: It is not really clear what your actual question is. Can you please try to explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: hmm.. actually i have an application  in which the user specifies the no of recordings.. i have to display a separate page corresponding to each recording .. wat i am currently doing is actually keeping the no of maximum number of activities in my

Comment: Why do you need different activities for that? Why can't a single activity handle that? You can pass the required data as an `extra` in the `Intent`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to be a bit less vague. For what problem you want to use dynamic activities?
Why can't you use intents.

You should make your activity as you make every other activity but you should pass through parameters with your intent and let your activity show the information it needs based on the parameters.

Comment: hmm.. actually i have an application  in which the user specifies the no of recordings.. i have to display a separate page corresponding to each recording .. wat i am currently doing is actually keeping the no of maximum number of activities in my project and opening it through intent ..wat i want to do to have a single java activity and show it 'n' no of imes according to user input